# How to remove mapped network drive with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create and remove a new mapped network drive using PowerShell.

It creates the mapped drive, however I can't seem to remove the mapped drive. The error message I receive is:

> Dir : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\P' because it does not exist.

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -Root "\\VM-Blue-Robin\Testing" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" 
#Get-PSDrive P | Remove-PSDrive
#Remove-PSDrive -Name P -Force
#Remove-PSDrive P, Z
```

All Google and Stack Overflow has suggested to me thus far is using the commands that I have previously commented out. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong but had a feeling it could be done to the location of my files perhaps?

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages using `Remove-PSDrive`?

Comment: @TobyU it ays Dir : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\P' because it does not exist. However when I run Dir P, or Get-PSDrive. I can see the drive does exist

Comment: If you intend to remove the drive soon, why do you add the `-Persist` parameter and I'D then add a `-Sope` to minimize possible other processes stepping in.

Comment: The error is because your running `dir P` instead of `dir P:` You need the `:` to signify a drive not a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're running `dir P` instead of `dir P:` You need the `:` to signify a drive not a folder.

`dir` (which in Powershell is a actually an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)) can read multiple areas of the OS so you need to be more specific with what you tell it.

Examples:

- File system: `Get-ChildItem C:`
- Registry: `Get-ChildItem HKCU:`
- Certificate Store: `Get-ChildItem cert:`

Whilst with `Get/Remove-PSDrive` commands you are specifically telling it you want a `"FileSystem"` drive so it knows that `Name` is a drive letter.

---

With regards to removing the drive, either of the two commands you've listed will work fine:

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -Root "\\VM-Blue-Robin\Testing" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" 

Get-PSDrive P | Remove-PSDrive
Remove-PSDrive -Name P -Force
```